# Temporarily login to another windows domain

Tags: windows-vista, windows-domain

I'm using Vista, and need to temporarily (1 day a week at a client) logon to another windows domain (my laptop is on the work domain, and I don't want to have to put the machine permanently on the client's domain).

I need to actually logon to the domain, because I need to use windows authentication for things like SQL Server, I know that you can put in the username/pass for file shares.

I have a login for the domain, and admin rights on my machine.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog entry seems to help with a lot of cross-domain issues: http://www.olegsych.com/2009/05/crossing-domain-boundaries-windows-authentication/

I've successfully used the `runas /user:domain\account /netonly <program>` command to start up sqlwb.exe and therefore connect to sql server. It also seems to work with other network applications.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a domain account, you should be able to authenticate to the target machine with your domain credentials and have those credentials passed for other operations (such as your SQL login).  Try authenticating to the [IPC Share](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPC_share) on the target machine as follows.  Run a command prompt as administrator and do ...

```
net use \\10.1.1.1\IPC$ /u:DOMAIN\UserName password
```

Substitute 10.1.1.1 with the IP Address of the computer you want to connect to and put your credentials in properly for the /u switch.

Comment: hmm, running that command gives me "The command completed successfully." in the command line, but when connecting to sql, I get an error message "Cannot generate SSPI context".

Comment: Apparently this solution stopped working with SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 0):

This solution is supposed to work with 2005

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/conversation.aspx?messageid=32222857&threadid=31792004

The solution given is for the management studio.

Answer (score -1):

[define trust relationship](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/c0008874.htm) and after 1 day manually rollback  and delete that definition.

Trust relationships are an administration and communication link between two domains. A trust relationship between two domains enables user accounts and global groups to be used in a domain other than the domain where the accounts are defined.

Comment: Not even remotely possible - if I'm onsite at a client their domain isn't even on the same network as my work one (so communication between them is impossible, let alone the issue of getting their or our network admins to trust another domain (especially for short-term clients)